# Help making Montgomery Pie layer properly

Tags: pie

When it comes to "putting the pie together" before baking, the recipe handed down by my great aunt states to pour liquid in bottom of uncooked pie shell, THEN "spread" topping on top of pie.

How in the world is this possible? You cannot physically "spread" batter on top of a liquid. I've tried everything. The end result is still a "swirled" effect, when it's supposed to have a "cakey" top and "moist" bottom. I've followed the recipe to a "T", and 5 times now, same result.

I'm lost. Any takers? Yes, I would like to ask my great aunt but she passed away years ago.

Comment: Can you post the recipe you're using? Maybe it differs somehow from other recipes that are around. A quick search for the recipe shows they all use the same method you've described but, at a glance, I'd say the bottom liquid should be extremely dense as it's mostly molasses that has been further thickened with even more sugar.

Comment: Maybe your batter preparation is incorrect. If you have beaten enough air into it, it should be OK to spread over liquid, just like you can spread foam on top of water in a bathtub.

Comment: I'd never heard of Montgomery pie before your question. It looks tasty and I want to try making one now, so maybe I'll be able to help troubleshoot using a different recipe than your aunt's :)

Comment: I would spoon the batter over the top the layer (by which I mean in dollops, so you have small bits of batter all over) and lightly "spread" the dollops together.

Comment: I'd go with  djmadscribbler's approach, and possibly oil or wet down whatever you're using for spreading the topping.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that there is an unwritten/lost step of putting the pie in the oven for long enough to just set the liquid, before the topping is spread. That's certainly how I do lemon or lime custard pies with a topping.